# Endless compilation when loading unicode-math and using \bm

Tags: luatex, compiling, unicode-math, bm

In this MWE, `\bm` command results in endless compilation only if `unicode-math` is preloaded. How to fix such an error?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\bm{\Phi}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `bm` if you load `unicode-math`. Use its facilities to declare a bold maths version.

Comment: It doesn't result in endless compilation. It results in an error. That error should be part of your question.

Comment: @cfr On my PC it took a long time to crash or even not. So, this is why it is endless to me. I recently used `unicode-math` in my document that has a lot of `\bm`s, so it would be better for me to resolve this clash instead of going through all my document.

Comment: These are incompatible approaches to typesetting mathematics. Drop one or the other. Define `\bm` to something if you need to.

Comment: A compilation error is not a 'crash'. It is an error. The code does not give a fatal error i.e. TeX does not give up. But the code you've shown definitely produces an error and not endless compilation. Are you saying that precisely this code didn't give you an error when compiled with LuaLaTeX on your machine? I suppose it could be version-specific. Maybe we have different versions.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it is continuously compiling until telling me that the command `lualatex.exe` crashed. Maybe it is something related to my PC and its OS status.

Comment: `lualatex.exe` tells you that `lualatex.exe` crashed? That doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean that your *editor* says that. In that case, there will be an error in the log. However, I find it is usually easier to compile from the command line when troubleshooting. Editors attempt to hide stuff from you which is not usually helpful when debugging.

Comment: @cfr You are right. I will consider the terminal next time in such a case.

Comment: You can always look at the `.log` instead. I just find it easier as the compiler stops and I can choose whether to ignore the error, in the hope that continuing will reveal the problem more clearly, or do something else. (Also, you can't pick 'h` for more help at the prompt if you aren't doing it interactively.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compilation is not 'endless'. It ends rather quickly, in fact, with an error

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
\mitPhi 
l.24 $\bm{\Phi}
             $
?
```

This is not, I think, very surprising. `unicode-math` is not likely to be compatible with `bm`. Instead, use `unicode-math`s facilities.

> *If you use Unicode maths, you must use it consistently. It is **either** a traditional TeX-font-based set up for maths **or** one based on Microsoft's MATH table extension to the OpenType format. If you want the latest OT whizzes and bangs, go with the whizzes and bangs. If you want a quiet night in, stay at home instead. You can't do both on the same night.*

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\Phi\symbf{\Phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image: medium and bold series Unicode maths symbols]